# ask for help for a sum (sigma) function

Tags: python, numpy, sum

need help to calculate this:

[image: function]

so, the total number of y is equal to number of x, and each y is calculated with one x and several a. 
My code list below, it gives the correct results for a0. what is a simple way to calculate this? maybe a different version can also verify the results.

Thanks a lot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([1,2,3,4],float) # here we can give several a
b = np.asarray(list(enumerate(a)))
x = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,10) 
y1 = [] 

for r in x:
    y1.append(np.exp(np.sum((1-r)**2*a*((2*b[:,0]+1)*r-1+r)*(r-1+r)**(b[:,0]-1)))) 

y1=np.asarray(y1)
```

Comment: you should do vector multiplication. you already have np arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write almost literally the same in numpy:

```
def f(x, a):
    x, a = np.asanyarray(x), np.asanyarray(a)
    x = x[:, None]        # create new dimension to sum along
    i = np.arange(len(a)) # create counter
    return np.sum((1-x)**2 * a * ((2*i + 1) * x - (1-x)) * (x - (1-x))**(i-1), axis=-1)
```

As a side note: there are obvious algebraic simplifications you could take advantage of.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have some questions, 1, is x, a here a tuple, while each component is an array?  2, is the meaning of axis=-1 sum along all axes?

Comment: @Z.Nie 1) No, x is a 2d array, so you can address individual elements as x[i, j]. However, the second dimension in this case is 1, so `j` will have to be zero (in this case, not in general). `axis=-1` means sum along the last axis therefore the original dimension of `x` which is axis 0 is left intact. The last dimension in the example is populated by `i` and `a` and these are collapsed  away with that axis.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. In your code, if return ((1-x)**2 * a * ((2*i + 1) * x - (1-x)) * (x - (1-x))**(i-1)), not sum, it gives a array with shape(10,4). But when I define the same x, a, i, and calculate ((1-x)**2 * a * ((2*i + 1) * x - (1-x)) * (x - (1-x))**(i-1)), it gives an error. How to interpret this difference?

Comment: @Z.Nie You probably left out the `x = x[:, None]` this creates a new axis at the position of `None`, so the new shape of `x` is (10, 1). When the expression is evaluated all operands with smaller `ndim` will be filled up with new axes on the left, so the shapes of `a` and `i` both become (1, 4). (10,1) and (1,4) are then broadcasted to (10, 4). The rule for things to be broadcastable is that each dimension must either match the corresponding dimension of the other operands or be 1.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.